# Bootstrap popover (placement: 'top') behaviors incorrect in IE8

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer-8, popover

Here's the javascript code of the pop-over part:

```
$('#view_case).popover({
    html: true,
    placement: 'top',
    title: 'Test Cases',
    content: function() {
        return $('#case_list').html();
    }
});
```

And the screenshot of it from IE8:

[image]

There's a small white triangle above the button, which shouldn't be there.

And I noticed [the tutorial page of Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#popovers) has the same issue. But when the placement is 'right', it just works fine in IE8.

So is this a common bug? Do we have some workaround for this?

Comment: do you want the color of the arrow to be white as the background of the popup container...??

Comment: Sure, or can I just remove the while triangle?

Comment: white triangle it is generated via pseudo classes... how you done this?

Comment: @SaurabhLP You mean how to reproduce? I'm using IE8, and the tutorial page of Bootstrap shows similar effect.

Comment: yes i know, in my ie8 its showing fine... http://i.imgur.com/KpRPeBy.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested this example with IE8 and it worked perfectly:

HTML:

```
<p>
    <a rel="popover" title="Here It Is" data-content="This is it!" href="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/index.html" target="_blank">
        Learn more about Bootstrap
    </a>
</p>
```

Javascript:

```
$('a').popover({
    placement: 'top',
    trigger: "hover"
});
```

You can [try it here](http://jsbin.com/egamiw/1).

The triangle you mention is present even if the placement is "right" and appears on Firefox too, although is the same colour as the popover background. So it's a bug.

Comment: OK so it's a bug.. Well I just removed the `.popover .arrow.after` class, the white arrow disappeared, although the style also changed in other browsers, but I think I can go with that.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your Jquery declaration with this, you missed a comma:-

```
$('#view_case').popover({
    html: true,
    placement: 'top',
    title: 'Test Cases',
    content: function() {
        return $('#case_list').html();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a typo when I retyped it here.

Comment: I removed the `.popover .arrow.after` class, the white arrow disappeared. I just take it as a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

I had issue with bootstrap popover (positioned left) in IE8 browser with double callout arrow pointer (not in IE9 with Browse mode IE8 and document mode IE8 standards).

I could fix this issue with IE8 fallback support CSS

```
.popover .arrow { 
    margin-right: 10px !important; /* adjusting the right position */
    border: 1px transparent; /* setting border to transparent */
}
```

Hope this would help.