# Nonfunctional Popover with Bootstrap & Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

You can see my entire app here at https://github.com/MaxPleaner/tryme . Compare the popover functionality of the root page with the popover functionality here: https://github.com/MaxPleaner/tryme-static (this is a non-rails version of the same code).

I am using the bootstrap-sass gem.

Answer (score 1):

First don't introduce spaces between attributes and values in your html, like this:

```
... data-placement = "bottom"
```

Here you have an working example: http://jsbin.com/egamiw/1/edit from an previous [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16854080/1006863)

Comment: didn't fix it. I'm considering just trying the other gem. I'm just a noob so I don't mind messing around with this kind of superficial stuff. EDIT I guess there's not really another gem, so I wish I could figure this out.